# Date was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, windows, datetime, raspberry-pi

kinda got an issue that I cant solve right now.

I've got a discord bot running on my raspberry pi, which has a system for automated messages that are sent after a certain amount of time, or an exact date, has passed.

My code works on Windows when debugging there, but the console throws a warning on Linux when running the published project.

The date is taken from a table in my MySQL database and put into a DataTable. The code that grabs the date from the DataRow is:

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(row["datetime"].ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Why is it happening? No matter how I format the string (dots, dashes or slashes), the warning persists. The messages are not sent.

I even tried removing invisible whitespaces with regex, doesnt work either.
(The regex in question, though I scrapped it since it yielded no fruit anyways)

```
Regex.Replace($"{row["datetime"].ToString()}", @"[^\d\s\.:]", string.Empty);
```

[image: Warning in Raspberry Console]

Comment: What is the datatype of the column on the MySql db?

Comment: It's "DATETIME" of course.

Comment: `DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(row["datetime"]);`

Comment: Then why do you want to convert a DateTime to a string and then back to a DateTime? A DateTime column is already a .... datetime. You just need a cast or at least a check for nulls and then a cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If RDBMS type is `DateTime` then why should we convert to `string` and then parse it back to `DateTime`? Let's do it direct:

```
 DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(row["datetime"]);
```

and let .net *convert* *boxed* `DateTime` (`row["datetime"]` is of type `object`?) to `DateTime`

Comment: There's no neex to "`Convert`" or be stuck in the "convert" mentality. It's already a `DateTime` value. Casting unboxes without the additional layers that just end up casting anyway. `DateTime datetime = (DateTime)row["datetime"];`

Comment: Agreed with @madreflection: the whole `Convert.To` mentality needs to stop. I see it all over the place on [so], especially with ADO.net code. It's completely unnecessary and a straight cast would have done the job

Answer (score 0):

The error message is letting you know the issue.

You have :

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(row["datetime"].ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Notable, you are saying that the date format is going to be "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Then your error message is saying that you couldn't parse :

```
8/2/2021 2:00:00 PM
```

Which is essentially a format of "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt" (Assuming that days come before months).

If you change your code to :

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(row["datetime"].ToString(), "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You should be good to go. DateTime.ParseExact does what it says on the tin, it parses the date format *exactly* how you say it should come. If you aren't sure you can use DateTime.Parse() (But you can occassionally run into issues where days/months are around the wrong way).

Tested using the following code :

```
var myDateString = "8/2/2021 2:00:00 PM";
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(myDateString, "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(datetime.ToString());
```

Comment: It doesn't. As I said in my post, I tried it with slashes, with dots, and with dashes. It doesn't work. Not to mention that it works on Windows, just not on Linux.

Comment: Can you ensure that the code is exactly as I posted (including the time portion, for example you need the tt), and then run it again and post the error? Because the error is very specific that you are trying to parse a datetime with slashes and your code clearly is not set up to parse it.

Comment: I did, the error is the same I am afraid.
https://imgur.com/a/vYsCwno

Comment: Cool. Edited my answer, it's still the date format, because you are using AM/PM you need to use lowercase h, and because your days/months do not have a prefix of 0, then you need to use a single d/m etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues--at the highest level, your ParseExact method is encountering a Date Time string that does not match the supplied format.

According to the code you posted, the expected format of is `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss`, and in your exception exception, shows a Date time string (`8/2/2021 2:00:00 PM`) that does not match:

- contains `/` and your expected format has `.`
- `dd` is a 2-digit day, but the input date time string only has single digit days
- `MM` expects a two digit month and the input date time only has a single digit month
- the string contains `AM/PM`, and your format neglects to account for that.

Finally it's not clear if your date format is Month Day Year, or Day Month year.

The second issue, is that `ParseExact` should be enclosed in a `try/catch` block, so that your code can handle the case when an unexpected formatted date time string is passed in, and not crash.

To solve this, wrap your call into a try/catch, and gracefully handle the `FormatException`

And then make sure the Format string matches the expected input string.

[Here is the .NET reference for the various DateTime format tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)